# ALSA output not working properly on RME RayDat

Tags: linux, audio, plugins, output, alsa

I'm trying to play output sound on my Linux Gentoo with ALSA to RME RayDat sound intereface. The configuration file is

```
pcm.mixer {
        type dmix
        ipc_key 10000
        ipc_key_add_uid true
        ipc_perm 0666
        slave {
                pcm "hw:2,0"
                format S32_LE
                rate 48000
                period_time 10666
                channels 36
        } 
} 
pcm.device_out { 
        type plug
        slave.pcm mixer
        ttable {
                0 { 0 1 }
        }
 }
```

I can hear output but the sound is not continuous. And the weird thing is, that input device (dsnoop type) set up with the same parameters is working without any problem.

Is there anyone experienced with setting up ALSA working with RME RayDat or other external sound device?

Note: When I send the output to the device type "route", it works, but type "dmix" is a problem. And I need to mix multiple streams together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such an "easy" definition of ALSA pcm device, I was not able to open RME Raydat output properly, so I had to use Jack. It runs perfectly.